# Why digest cycle does not get called automatically for promise in unit test?

Tags: angularjs

```
it("should update code when the key is changed through selector", function () {
      var Code = "123";
      var expectedCode;

      service.updateCode(Code).then(function (expectedCode) {
        expectedCode = expectedCode;
      });

      // promises are resolved/dispatched only on next $digest cycle
      $rootScope.$apply(); 
      expect(expectedCode).toEqual(`enter code here`Code);
    });
```

Why we need to call $rootScope.apply() explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Promises are resolved/rejected during the digest cycle which can be triggered by you by calling `$rootScope.$apply()` or even `$rootScope.$digest`.

So basically by calling that you are telling angular to process the handlers for the promises that you've resolved/rejected in order to evaluate the results for testing.

When your application is running the digest loop is evaluated automatically for things that happen with the scope of your angular application, so you do not need to call this directly within your application for most cases.

Comment: I understand that. Why digest cycle does not get automatically gets called in testing?

Comment: If you are creating your tests using angular mocks I believe that it is not doing that. But my typical tests involve me instantiating the test structure manually (not via angular DI) so the angular framework is never loaded, just a JavaScript object being created.

Answer (score 0):

Because then it would be a lot harder to test. I know this may sound counter-intuitive, but once you get a little bit into promise testing you'll understand what I mean.

It would be a pain to expect() stuff from promises, because you would always run into race-conditions. In your example if you omit the $apply(), due to the async nature of promises, the expect would probably be called before the promise is resolve.

So by manually having to $apply/$digest it basically changes your async stuff into a synchronous.